# Mongodb _id and how to implement it in php to make references between collections

Tags: php, mongodb

Since I'm new to Mongodb, i have some confusion with mongodb ids.

1. in Mysql, we can define any variable as a primary key.is it possible to define any variable as the primery key in mongodb like that?
2. in console we define _id as _id : objectId("4c4ba5c0672c685e5e8aabf3"). how to do same thing in php.and what is the argument ("4c4ba5c0672c685e5e8aabf3") where it come from? are there any way to genarate this argument by a function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Documents in MongoDB are required to have an `_id` field, whose value is both immutable and unique to the collection. The [ObjectId](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/) type, which PHP represents as the [MongoId](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mongoid.php) class, is typically used for this field. Due to its composition, it is well-suited for ensuring uniqueness across a cluster, similar to UUIDs.

If you read through the [record documents](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#documents-records) documentation, which discusses the structure of documents stored in collections, you'll find that any BSON value may be used as an `_id`, with the exception of an array (due to how MongoDB handles indexing of array fields). Within the same collection, you are free to use different ID types across your documents, although its advised to be consistent for your personal sanity.

```
// Allowed
db.foo.insert({ _id: 1 })
db.foo.insert({ _id: 'abc' })
db.foo.insert({ _id: ObjectId() })
db.foo.insert({ _id: { x: 1, y: 2 }})
db.foo.insert({ _id: { x: 1, o: ObjectId() }})
db.foo.insert({ _id: { x: 1, a: [1, 2, 3] }})

// Not allowed
db.foo.insert({ _id: [1, 2, 3] })
db.foo.insert({ _id: ['a', ObjectId()] })
```

Although ObjectIds are often printed as 24-character hexadecimal strings, it's important to remember that they are really their own [BSON type](http://bsonspec.org/#/specification) -- a 12-byte binary value. If you're querying for a document by its ObjectId in PHP, you'll want to match on a MongoId value, like so:

```
// Matches
$collection->findOne([ '_id' => new MongoId('4c4ba5c0672c685e5e8aabf3') ]);

// Doesn't match (unless a document's ID was really that string
$collection->findOne([ '_id' => '4c4ba5c0672c685e5e8aabf3' ]);
```

Lastly, if you'd like to generate ObjectIds in PHP, you can simply construct MongoId instances as you like by passing no argument to its constructor. The MongoId class has a `__toString()` method, so you can also cast it to a string to get back its 24-character string representation. Likewise, if you need to construct a MongoId from a 24-character string, you can pass that as the single constructor argument (as we did in the query above).

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/:

> ObjectId is a 12-byte BSON type, constructed using:
>
> - 4-byte value representing the seconds since the Unix epoch,
> - 3-byte machine identifier,
> - 2-byte process id, and
> - 3-byte counter, starting with a random value.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mongoid.php, http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.ensureindex.php